# Constructor DI + Unity 2.0 + issue with resolving dependency

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    IEmployeeTask _employeeTask;

    public HomeController()
    {
        _employeeTask = new UnityContainer().Resolve<IEmployeeTask>();
    }

    public HomeController(IEmployeeTask employeeTask)
    {
        _employeeTask = employeeTask;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }       

    public ActionResult GetAndDisplayEmployee()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetAndDisplayEmployee(int empid)
    {            
        return View(_employeeTask.GetEmployeeModelFromService(empid));            
    }
}
```

**Global.asax.cs:**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IEmployeeModelMap, EmployeeModelMap>();
    container.RegisterType<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();
    container.RegisterType<IEmployeeTask, EmployeeTask>();
    container.RegisterType<IEmployee, Employee>();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

**Unity Dependency Resolver:**

```
 public class UnityDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
 {
     readonly IUnityContainer _container;
     public UnityDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container)
     {
         this._container = container;
     }
     public object GetService(Type serviceType)
     {
         try
         {
             return _container.Resolve(serviceType);
         }
         catch
         {
             return null;
         }
     }
     public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
     {
         try
         {
             return _container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
         }
         catch
         {
             return new List<object>();
         }
     }
 }
```

**Employee Task class:**

```
 public class EmployeeTask: IEmployeeTask
 {        
     IEmployeeService _employeeService;        
     IEmployeeModelMap _employeeModelMap;

     public EmployeeTask(IEmployeeService employeeService, IEmployeeModelMap employeeModelMap)
     {
         _employeeService = employeeService;
         _employeeModelMap = employeeModelMap;
     }

     public EmployeeViewModel GetEmployeeModelFromService(int empId)
     {
         return _employeeModelMap.ToModel(_employeeService.GetEmployeeFromEntities(empId));
     }
}
```

Now, i have used unity 2.0 application block. Tried to resolve the dependency of the controller using unity with out using Custom Controller factory.
     I am stuck with below error.

> The current type, DataProviderInfrastructure.IEmployeeTask, is an
>   interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Unity, but my guess would be that it attempts to use your parameterless constructor where you try to resolve the dependency. Creating this constructor is very very wrong. First - it defeats the purpose of having dependency injection and second - you create new container inside - which will be empty so it obviously can't resolve any dependencies. Try removing this from your code:

```
public HomeController()
{
    _employeeTask = new UnityContainer().Resolve<IEmployeeTask>();
}
```

Comment: Why was this down voted?  When I threw together a quick app using the provided code, it worked fine (and it never hit the parameterless constructor).  When I forced it to use the parameterless constructor, it blew up, because (as Lukas already stated) the container instance in the controller is different from the one in the global.asax.cs (where all the dependencies are registered).  If removing the parameterless constructor does not solve the issue, there is probably something we are not seeing that is causing the issue.

Comment: Unity chooses the constructor with the largest number of parameters, and will not choose a default constructor if another choice is available.